# Can one modify footprints in Gpredict?

Tags: satellites, software, line-of-sight, gpredict

I have created a TLE to represent my theoretical satellite whose orbit I wish to plot using Gpredict. I have managed to load it all up onto the program and it is looking good, but one thing remains - I want to work out an accurate-ish pass scenario, and as such want to be able to modify the satellite's footprint. Is this possible? Or does Gpredict just use a default value of 'beam angle' and scale the footprint according to altitude?

Also, while I am here, are there typical values for an x-band satellite's footprint? I have found that they are typically >1000km diameter but not much else more than that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footprint calculated by gpredict (and other satellite tracking software) is the area from which the satellite appears above de horizon (or, equivalently, the patch of earth seen from the satellite). This is independent of any radio link the satellite may possess.

So the answer is no. You cannot *modify footprints* on gpredict.

This has nothing to do with antenna footprints for geostationary satellites, which is the area on earth covered by the satellite service. This depends strongly on the antenna design and satellite attitude.